# Lenovo y580, Windows 7 and Ubuntu (i Hope so...)

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 13.10, windows-7, lenovo

I love Ubuntu so I wanted to have one on my laptop. I have Lenovo Y580 with Core i3-3310m version. I have Windows 7 (for my work, unfortunetly) but I also wanted to have Ubuntu. My first attempt to go for it was about 6 months ago and I completly lost all my data, because of hell knows what. So now, I want to ask you to help me with installing it.

I have a 13.10 version on DVD disc and I start to install it. When it comes to option to check a other OS, it just don't see Windows 7. 
How can I install Ubuntu next to Windows when it does not see it?

And other question - Installer sees some wierd partitions from god knows where. In Windows there are

- C: (~100GB0),
- D:(~400GB),
- E:(~420GB),
- UNALLOCATED (~70GB for ubuntu)

and here in Ubuntu are only two of them, one ~800GB and the rest is the one that I've created for it ~70GB).

Any ideas what the hell is goin' on?

Comment: What option did you select at `Installation Type` window during installation?' Did you `select something else` at `Insatllation type` screen during installation?

Comment: Yes, I have options to erase disk (which I don't want to do) and use "Something Else". Than on the next window, it shows that I have no other OS.

Answer (score 0):

Click Following Links : :

[Install Ubuntu Along Side Windows 7](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q77opXWdaj8)

[Installing ubuntu on a laptop that already contains windows 7](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1557105)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @chaos Is that necessary ?

Comment: See this meta answer: http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6153/185729

Comment: Can you improve this answer?